# Why isn't JavaScript's Intl.NumberFormat() rounding numbers correctly?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, intl

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {  maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(-4.125)
```

This returns -4.13, whilst `round(-4.125, 2)` returns the correct value of -4.12, rounded towards the higher value, closer to 0

Comment: Hi Nicu, which library does round belong to? Math.round?

Comment: I use both Math.round or round from moment, they both return the correct result while intl returns the wrongly calculated one.